An alternative way to prove that $\Bbb A^1$ is the normalization of $V(y^2-x^3-x^2)\subset\Bbb A^2$
I had some doubts to resolving this exercise. Now thanks to the answers in Normalization of the variety $V(Y^2-X^3-X^2)\subset\Bbb A^2$ I can understand it really clear, so thank you.
My problem is that my teacher gave me (when he sent me the assignment) some steps (apparently in a different way than the previous post), but I don't  understand why he suggest me this form. Which one do you suggest me to use? Could you explain to me briefly what do the next steps consist of, please? (I'm not asking about resolving it I'm just want to understand the reason for each one.)

$K(X) = \frac{\mathbb{C(x)[y]}}{<y^2-x^3-x^2>}$

$\overline {\mathbb{C[x]}}^{A(X)} = A(X)$

$\alpha(x) + \beta(x)\cdot y$ $\in \overline{A(X)}^{K(X)} \iff$ the coefficients of its minimum polynomial over $\mathbb{C(X)}$ are in $\mathbb{C[x]}$

Conclude $\overline{A(X)}^{K(X)}=A(X)$


